# Maintaining UITableViewCell state between scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` in which there is a *like* button and *total likes* count.

When the user taps, an API call is made and the number is incremented on the backend and that particular object is set as `liked`.

If the user taps on it again, the process repeats, except the count is decremented and the `liked` flag is unset.

I am currently finding, when the my cell is scrolled off screen the count is reset. This makes sense if my understand of `UITableViewCell`'s is correct.

I'd like to avoid fetching the entire table view again on each tap, so I was hoping I could maintain some sort of local state of dis/liked items.

I cannot work out how best to balance the logic between being able to manage the real counts and my local counts.

To make matters possibly more complicated, there is a web app that consumes the same api's, so I need to ensure I cleanse this local cache each time the `UITableView` is refreshed.

I have a `static` prop on `BaseRecognitionFeedCell` that looks like:

```
static var localLikes = [String: Int]()
```

And a method within my class that is called when the icon is tapped:

```
@objc private func handleTapLikeButton() -> Void {
    guard let content = content, let externalId = content.externalId else { return }

    if BaseRecognitionFeedCell.localLikes[externalId] == nil {
        var likes: Int
        if !content.liked {
            didLikeFeedItem?(content.type, externalId)
            likes = content.likes + 1
        } else {
            // call didDislikeBinding
            likes = content.likes - 1
        }

        BaseRecognitionFeedCell.localLikes[externalId] = likes
        likeRecognitionButton.setTitle("\(likes)", for: .normal)
    } else {
        var likes: Int
        if content.likes < BaseRecognitionFeedCell.localLikes[externalId] {
            didLikeFeedItem?(content.type, externalId)
            likes = BaseRecognitionFeedCell.localLikes[externalId] + 1
        } else {
            // call didDislikeBinding
            likes = BaseRecognitionFeedCell.localLikes[externalId] - 1
        }

        BaseRecognitionFeedCell.localLikes[externalId] = likes
        likeRecognitionButton.setTitle("\(likes)", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I am sure there must be a way to do this and I am just missing something.

Currently the count increments, however on scroll it resets. Also, once clicked, clicking it again does not decrement the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed that you have an array of models , then add this to the model

```
var numOfLikes:Int
var isLiked:Bool  /// for me
```

the above 2 properties must have a value upon receiving the request ,  when you click like/dislike in a cell init the api request with the proper parameters given the reference to the cell indexPath if liked

```
model[cellIndex].numOfLikes += 1
model[cellIndex].isLiked = true
```

and if disliked

```
model[cellIndex].numOfLikes -= 1
model[cellIndex].isLiked = false
```

this update need to be reflected to the model not to the cell directly , as it's dequeued inside `cellForRowAt` re-assign the values , then to refresh the cell when you receive the response

```
// here update the model 
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:IndexPath(row:lastClickedIndex,section:0)) as? MYCellName {
  // here cell is visible refresh it  
} 
else { 
// don't do anything as the cell isn't here meaning that it will refresh with latest content when re-appear with the automatic call to `cellForRowAt` 
}
```